# OpenCV create 3 mat objects from YUV_420_888 planes

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android

Is there anyway to create **3 mat objects** to hold YUV_420_888 planes data.
One for Y, another for U and the last one for V plane.

I don't want to convert them to BGR or anything, just hold the data as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Splitting of the Mat.

For example in a BGR Image (I'll show you in c++ because i'm not that into opencv4Android):

```
cv::Mat src = cv::imread("some.png");
cv::Mat planes[3];
cv::split(src, planes);
```

If you have a BGR you would now have the R-Plane in the `planes[2]`.

Another possibility is, to just get the Planes Buffer e.g.(Java Android now):

```
/* Get your Image somehow */
Image.Plane Y = img.getPlanes[0];
Image.Plane U = img.getPlanes[1];
Image.Plane V = img.getPlanes[2];

//now just for Y e.g.
ByteBuffer yBuffer = Y.getBuffer();
byte[] yBytes = new Byte[yBuffer.remaining()];
yBuffer.get(yBytes);

//read the byte data into a cv::Mat
```